# Pythonic equivalent of unshift or redo?

Tags: python, redo

I'm learning Python, and I have a situation where I want to consume items from an iterator.  The tricky part is that under certain conditions, I want to "un-iterate."  That is, put an item back onto the front of the iterator before I loop.

For example, suppose I'm picking apples from a tree.  My fruit basket can only hold 10kg before it needs to be emptied.  But I have to pick each apple before I can weigh it and determine if this apple would exceed the capacity of the basket.

In a language like Perl, I could `unshift()` the apple back onto the tree, and then let the loop expression re-pick the apple:

```
while ($apple = shift(@tree)) {
  $wt = weight($apple);
  if ($wt + weight(@basket) > 10) {
    send(@basket);
    @basket = ();
    unshift(@tree, $apple);
  } else {
    push(@basket, $element);
  }
}
```

Or else I can also use `redo`, which resumes processing at the top of block, without evaluating the loop expression.  So the same apple can be re-processed, after the basket has been emptied.

```
while ($apple = shift(@tree)) {
  $wt = weight($apple);
  if ($wt + weight(@basket) > 10) {
    send(@basket);
    @basket = ();
    redo;
  } else {
    push(@basket, $apple);
  }
}
```

What would be the most **pythonic** solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: if $wt > 10 then there is an infinite loop (the first example eats all memory, the second one just never halts).

Comment: @J.F.: You're right, but in this case it's safe to assume no single apple will exceed 10kg.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why bother with unshifting when the else clause should always occur?

```
for apple in tree:
    if (apple.weight + basket.weight) > 10:
       send(basket)
       basket.clear()
    basket.add(apple)
```

Anyway, I'm fairly certain that Python doesn't have the sort of behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Just to clarify: Python's *builtin iterators* don't have the sort of behavior he's looking for.

Comment: This appears to be the most straightforward solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

> I'm learning Python, and I have a situation where I want to consume items from an iterator. The tricky part is that under certain conditions, I want to "un-iterate." That is, put an item back onto the front of the iterator before I loop.

Here's a simple solution:

```
class MyIterator(object):   # undo-able iterator wrapper
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        super(MyIterator, self).__init__()
        self.iterator = iter(iterable)
        self.stack = []

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.stack:
            return self.stack.pop()
        return self.iterator.next()  # Raises StopIteration eventually

    def undo(self, item):
        self.stack.append(item)
```

```
for i in  MyIterator(xrange(5)): print i
0
1
2
3
4
```

```
rng = MyIterator(xrange(5))
rng.next()
0
rng.next()
1
rng.undo(1)
rng.next()
1
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers my original question about how one could implement an unshift-like operation.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say that [the most Pythonic solution is the simplest one](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2004-March/253893.html). Instead of trying to wrap an iterator in a generator expression that allows you to "backtrack" or something similarly complex, use a while loop, as you have in Perl! **[Iterators don't mix very nicely with mutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299135/when-i-sort-a-list-what-happens-to-its-iterators)**, anywho.

Simple translation of your implementation (ignoring [@Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418915/pythonic-equivalent-of-unshift-or-redo#418946)'s optimization):

```
while tree:
    apple = tree.pop(0)
    if apple.weight + basket.weight > 10:
        basket.send()
        basket.clear()
        tree.insert(0, apple) # Put it back.
    else:
        basket.append(apple)
```

Or, you could use a `peek`-like functionality with ordered sequence indices:

```
while tree:
    apple = tree[0] # Take a peek at it.
    if apple.weight + basket.weight > 10:
        basket.send()
        basket.clear()
    else:
        basket.append(tree.pop(0))
```

If you don't like the "simple" argument, check out the `collections.deque` iterators mentioned in the above (linked) thread.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to remember to step back from the problem.  Instead of focusing on a mechanism like unshift, it's best to solve the true problem in a more simple way.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to follow the other's suggestion of just removing the else clause, you can write your own `unshift` function that will work in a way similar to perl's with any iterable:

```
class UnshiftableIterable(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iter = iter(iterable)
        self._unshifted = [] # empty list of unshifted stuff
    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            if self._unshifted:
                yield self._unshifted.pop()
            else:
                yield self._iter.next()
    def unshift(self, item):
        self._unshifted.append(item)
```

Then in your code:

```
it = UnshiftableIterable(tree)
for apple in tree:
    if weigth(basket) + weight(apple) > MAX_WEIGHT:
        send(basket)
        basket = []
        it.unshift(apple)
    else:
        basket.append(apple)
```

Some testing of the `UnshiftableIterable`:

```
it = UnshiftableIterable(xrange(5))

for i in it:
    print '*',
    if i == 2:
        it.unshift(10)
    else:
        print i,
# output: * 0 * 1 * * 10 * 3 * 4
```

Comment: Your `UnshiftableIterator` is not an iterator (it has no `next()` method). It is iterable (it has `__iter__()` method).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: True. Changed name to reflect that.

Comment: `for apple in tree:` -> `for apple in it:`. Otherwise unshifted values are never used.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  It's good to see how to create an iterable class, even if I don't use this solution in this particular case.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a generator, an iterator that can receive modifications to its internal state via the send() method

https://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html#passing-values-into-a-generator

Comment: Thanks for this tip about send()!  I'm not sure I'll use it in this case, but it's great to know for the future.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, what you really want is list.insert(0,yourObject)

Answer (score 1):

While I was writing this @Patrick already suggested the same thing. But since I have written it I will paste the code anyways, with comments in code marking methods from Patrick.

```
import random

apples=[random.randint(1,3) for j in range(10)]
print 'apples',apples

basket=[]
y=6
baskets=[]

for i in range(len(apples)):
    if sum(basket+[apples[i]])>y:
        #basket is full                                                                                                                                     
        baskets.append(basket)#basket.send()                                                                                                                
        basket=[]#basket.empty()                                                                                                                            
    basket.append(apples[i])#add apple to basket                                                                                                            

print 'baskets',baskets
```

though this does not pop() the apples from the original iterator. Please remark if that's a desired behavior too.

the output

```
apples [1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3]
baskets [[1, 1, 3], [3, 1, 1], [3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently my upgraded version of [pythonizer](https://github.com/snoopyjc/pythonizer) doesn't handle `redo` but if I added it, I would probably implement it like this:

```
while (apple:=(tree.pop(0) if tree else None)):
    while True:
        wt = weight(apple)
        if wt+weight(*basket) > 10:
            sendit(basket)
            basket = []
            continue
        else:
            basket.append(apple)
        break
```

(Note: I had to change `send` to `sendit` because `send` is predefined in perl.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Back to the original question about impementing unshift, operator.delitem can be used to implement a simple non-OO function:

```
from operator import delitem

def unshift(l,idx):
    retval = l[0]
    delitem(l,0)
    return retval

x = [2,4,6,8]

firstval = unshift(x,0)

print firstval,x
```

2 [4, 6, 8]

Comment: That's not unshift -- that's shift.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way general way to push a value into an iterator in python.  A stack or linked list is better suited to that.

If you're iterating over a list or something, of course you can add the item manually back to the list.  But you can also iterate over objects which can't be manipulated in such a way.

If you want to use python to implement that algorithm, you'll have to choose a data structure that allows the operations you want to use.  I suggest the `.push()` and `.pop()` methods which let you treat lists as stacks.