# Remove multiple items from ArrayList during iterator

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, java-7

Is it safe to remove multiple items from an ArrayList while iterating through it with an iterator?

```
Iterator<String> iterator = nameList.iterator();
 while(iterator.hasNext()){
     String s = iterator.next();
     List<String> list = work(s);
     for (String s1 : list) {
        nameList.remove(s1);   
    }
}
```

The `work()` method gives back a list of names that should be removed from the nameList, during the runtime of while loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's not safe, and can throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. You can collect all the elements to be removed in a temporary `List`, and then call `list.removeAll(tmpList)` after the while loop to perform the removal.

```
Iterator<String> iterator = nameList.iterator();
List<String> removed = new ArrayList<>();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    String s = iterator.next();
    removed.addAll(work(s));
}
list.removeAll(removed);
```

I realize this can be less efficient, since you might be calling `work(s)` on `String`s the should have been removed from the `List` earlier. This can be improved by changing `tempList` to a `Set`, and only calling `work(s)` for `String`s not in the `Set`:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = nameList.iterator();
Set<String> removed = new HashSet<>();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    String s = iterator.next();
    if (!removed.contains(s)) {
        removed.addAll(work(s));
    }
}
list.removeAll(removed);
```

Comment: Yes, avoiding to call work(s) on a String that should have been removed in a previous loop is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: I will try your idea using a "removed" set. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Of course, then you don’t need to deal with an `Iterator` manually; `for(String s: nameList) { if(!removed.contains(s)) removed.addAll(work(s)); } list.removeAll(removed);`

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your logic if you use a ListIterator which is fail-safe. Below is a basic example :

```
Set<String> removed = new HashSet<>();
    ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

            ListIterator<String> iterator = nameList.listIterator();
             while(iterator.hasNext()){
                 String s = iterator.next();
                 if (!removed.contains(s)) {
        removed.addAll(work(s));
    }

            }


 nameList.removeAll(removed);
                 System.out.println(nameList);
```

With your logic, you have to account the performance. If performance is not a factor, you can go ahead and add/remove from a list through ListIterator.

Comment: That still throws a ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: just check with sysout statements that the list you are getting is empty or anything.

Comment: @Jayanth calling [remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove--) on the `ListIterator` exactly once per iteration step would be ok, but calling `removeAll` on the backing `List` is not.

Comment: Hi @Thommy, may be check whether you are removing an element from namelist which is already been removed or something...because my post is just to give you an idea of making use of ListIterator.

Comment: @Jayanth Yes that is exactly the problem, removing one works but I want to remove multiple in one iteration. I solved it using the "workaround" from  Eran's answer.

Answer (score 0):

As a previous answer said, removing an item from a iterated list is not safe. Here is a code that throws `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String s = iterator.next();
    list.remove("1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Iterator.remove()` (as opposed to `nameList.remove(s)`).

```
Iterator<String> iterator = nameList.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    String s = iterator.next();
    iterator.remove();
}
```

Also consider `nameList.clear()` and `nameList.removeAll(elementsToRemove)`.

Iterators are generally invalid after any modification to their underlying collections, except via the iterator itself. - [When I sort a List what happens to its iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299135/when-i-sort-a-list-what-happens-to-its-iterators)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html